# Is it possible to remove component styles from main JS bundle in Angular 10?

Tags: javascript, angular

My Angular 10 application has SSR using Angular Universal, and this way styles get inlined in style element on the page, which is fine, but those styles also end up in the main JS bundle. So they are duplicated and increase the byte size of the bundle. I have a couple of questions:

1. How to remove styles from the JS bundle?
2. Is it possible to create a separate CSS bundle for component styles?